# Id is not matching the expected pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to set up monitoring in our monitoring tool for our AWS OpenSearch clusters. I got almost all metrics to be parsed/fetched by using CloudWatch via cURL.

The script looks roughly like this

```js
var metrics_list = [
    'CPUUtilization:Percent',
    'MasterCPUUtilization:Percent',
    'ClusterStatus.green:Count',
    'ClusterStatus.yellow:Count',
    'ClusterStatus.red:Count',
    'SearchableDocuments:Count',
    'DiskQueueDepth:Count',
    'WriteThroughput:Bytes/Second',
    'ReadThroughput:Bytes/Second',
    'SearchLatency:Milliseconds',
    'WriteLatency:Seconds',
    'ReadLatency:Seconds',
    'IndexingLatency:Milliseconds',
    'SearchRate:Count',
    'WriteIOPS:Count/Second',
    'ReadIOPS:Count/Second',
    'FreeStorageSpace:Megabytes',
    '3xx:Count',
    '4xx:Count',
    '5xx:Count'
];

var metric_payload = [];
metrics_list.forEach(function(metric) {
    var parts = metric.split(':', 2);
    var name = parts[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
    metric_payload.push({
        'Id': name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + name.slice(1),
        'MetricStat': {
            'Metric': {
                'MetricName': parts[0],
                'Namespace': 'AWS/ES',
                'Dimensions': [{
                        'Name': 'ClientId',
                        'Value': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'DomainName',
                        'Value': os_instance_id
                    }
                ]
            },
            'Period': period,
            'Stat': 'Average',
            'Unit': parts[1]
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine for all of the metrics, except for the last three;

- `3xx:Count`
- `4xx:Count`
- `5xx:Count`

These are returning the following error:

> The value xxx for parameter MetricDataQueries.member.xx.Id is not matching the expected pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$.

```json
{
  "error": "Request failed with status code 400",
  "type": "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException",
  "message": "The value 3xx for parameter MetricDataQueries.member.18.Id is not matching the expected pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$.\nThe value 4xx for parameter MetricDataQueries.member.19.Id is not matching the expected pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]$.\nThe value 5xx for parameter MetricDataQueries.member.20.Id is not matching the expected pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]$."
}
```

What would be the correct way of fetching these metrics from cloudwatch?

Answer (score -1):

Your metric IDs must start with a lowercase letter.

As per the error, the `Id` field must conform to the `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` regex. It expects a string that *starts* with a lowercase letter & contains only alphanumeric characters.

With your current application logic, `3xx:Count`, `4xx:Count` and `5xx:Count` from your `metrics_list` will respectively have IDs of  `3xx`, `4xx` and `5xx`.

These don't start with a lowercase letter and won't be accepted by the API.

Comment: Hi ThomasVdBerge, did this answer your question?